# Remove sub-document from MongoDB if you don't know sub-document name

Tags: mongodb

How does one unset a sub-document from MongoDB if one doesn't know the specific name of the sub-document?

In otherwords, I'd like to identify the sub-document based on some or another value for its fields...however, the actual name of the sub-document isn't known. So I'd like to somehow identify this sub-document and then remove it.

For example, where I match the height field to 160, I'd like to remove the 'baboon' sub-document...

```
{ Document: {
    monkey: {
        height: 100,
        weight: 40
    },
    baboon: {
        height: 160,
        weight: 70
    }
}
```

I realise that arrays are another option ($ placeholders and $pull operators), but am trying to avoid as this introduces other complications elsewhere.

Comment: I guess you can do it in two operations. First findOne, and check the aninaml name in your app. Then do anoter operation which unset the selected animal.

Comment: I believe you have to change your datasctructure

Comment: you could have a **animal** collection with attributes *type*, *height*, and *weight*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of the [$redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) pipeline operator, if you use mongodb v2.6. Unless it is a production environment I strongly recommend you to upgrade your mongodb version to the latest to enjoy the full power of mongodb operators.

This probably is the simplest use case of the `$redact` stage operator.

- Start from the root document, check if the document has an attribute
  where height is 160.
- If the document has its height equal to 160, [PRUNE](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune) it. Else
  [DESCEND](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#descend) on to its sub documents.
- If a document at a level does not have an attribute named `height`,
  we assign an empty value to it, so that we can keep that document and
  traverse its sub documents.

Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$redact:{$cond:
               [{$eq:[{$ifNull:["$height",""]},160]},
                "$$PRUNE",
                "$$DESCEND"
               ]
          }
}
])
```

o/p:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54931b403e20905cb605a802"),
        "monkey" : {
                "height" : 100,
                "weight" : 40
        }
}
```

You can do an atomic update on the document once you get the document with redacted information:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$redact:{$cond:
               [{$eq:[{$ifNull:["$height",""]},160]},
                "$$PRUNE",
                "$$DESCEND"
               ]
          }
}
]).forEach(function(doc){
   db.collection.update({"_id":doc._id},doc)
})
```